# Link stylesheets and scripts to our website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any difference between linking a stylesheet or script to our website from EXTERNAL servers and uploading the stylesheet to our server and link to it? What are the benefits of uploading to our server?

Comment: No difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the external ones are served by a CDN server, that's means that your users probably have them cached ( for example jquery or other popular library )

Comment: How can i find that a link is served by CDN server?

Answer (score 0):

If you store something on your server it will mean your server will have to process more data, that is send your scripts or CSS together with every request. That will add some extra work for your server which may mean extra costs or slower responses.

The advantage of using links to external servers is less load on your server and also most of the popular frameworks like jQuery for example, they have your file available all over the world, so if user opens your website based in europe for example and he is based in USA he will not have to wait for file to be delivered across the world, but instead will most likely get that file from a location closer to him. Less traffic, less load on server and faster response times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is lots of difference:

1. If you will include stylesheet or script from external source then it will take time to load the page.
2. If you will include stylesheet or script from external source then it may causes not to load all due to firewall(I have faced this situation).
3. In future if there will change in the files then it will also reflect your site.
4. The security issue, anyone can add the code to track your data.

So always recommend to download and add these file from your on server instead of including  stylesheet or script from external source.